# Handling file uploads within SVN

Tags: svn, netbeans, file-upload, symlink, svnignore

I'm constantly having to propset svn:ignore on my uploaded files directories simply because svn:ignore doesn't work as expected. I'm working in NetBeans and our site is constantly under heavy development. I'm sick of "ignoring" the folders because it simply doesn't work how I expect it to. We have several upload directories and would like them to be completely ignored from version control. I thought of possibly using symlinks to store the files in a separate folder on my local machine, while leaving the actual directory empty. Does this sound like a logical solution?

Answer (score 1):

svn:ignore the entire directory, or write a svn:ignore rule to ignore everything

Beyond that, you could restructure your work flow to have a non svn controlled upload area.

It isn't clear why you would have a directory which isn't actually part of your source code checked into SVN for revisioning purposes, but perhaps there is a reason.  If at all possible, only check into SVN that which you really wish to revision.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried:

```
svn propset --recursive svn:ignore upload_directory_name *
```

Answer (score 0):

Your question doesn't state if you are using Netbeans Subversion plugin. If this is the case be sure to check [Always exclude folders from committing in SVN for Netbeans](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6144453/always-exclude-folders-from-committing-in-svn-for-netbeans)