# Always exclude folders from committing in SVN for Netbeans

Tags: svn, plugins, netbeans, repository

I use Netbeans 7.0 and the built-in SVN client for developing. I want to always exclude some files and folders from committing/updating (e.g. "cache" or "log", as they are not important for the repository as such).

I didn't find any setting to do so and also Netbeans didn't cover the topic in their FAQs... How can I achieve this?!

Comment: I have not used NetBeans 7 yet, but in older versions you could set the svn:ignore property on a folder by right-clicking it in the Projects window and choosing Subversion -> Svn properties. See also: http://svnbook.red-bean.com/en/1.1/ch07s02.html

Comment: svn propedit svn:ignore;  // then add the cache, log or wildcard files you want to ignore--one per line.  Save and exit.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As Mike said: in the projects window, right-click on a folder, go to "Subversion" -> "Svn Properties".

You will need to have the Subversion plugin installed for this to work.

Comment: This doesn't seem to work. I added `./app/cache ./app/log` to the properties values, but when I click commit, Netbeans still wants to commit those folders and does so.

Comment: Right-click on the cache folder and the log folder separately and exclude their contents. See if that helps.

Comment: mine wants to check in ./nbproject/private/private.xml. I have set the svn:ignore property on the file by explicit name and by wildcard. The file does not appear in the NetBeans Projects list (presumably because NB is filtering it). It does appear in the NetBeans Files list, but it seems that the option for subversion->ignore is greyed on *all* files in the file list.

Answer (score 3):

Inside netbean, right-click on a folder/file, go to "Subversion" -> Ignore.

I am using this and it is working for me.

Comment: This option is greyed out, only "Exclude from commit" is available. Why can it be disabled?

Comment: It may be greyed out sometimes, because it was there before. You can ignore only new files that was never committed. You cannot ignore files that are already in the repository.